# pandas.series get boolean if list in cell contains value

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a pandas series, where each cell has a list of values. I want to get a boolean, whether the list in the cell contains a value.

pandas series:

```
0          [1, 2, 2, 2]
1             [1, 2, 2]
2                [1, 2]
3                [1, 2]
4                [1, 2]
             ...       
1697    [1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
1698          [1, 2, 2]
1699             [1, 2]
1700          [1, 2, 2]
1701             [1, 2]
```

The "isin" doesn't work and neither does "1 in data['top-level']" as is just looks whether the 1 is in the whole series, not each cell.

I would appreciate some tips and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `in` with list comprehension:

```
mask = [1 in x for x in data['top-level']]
```

Or use `in` in [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
mask = data['top-level'].apply(lambda x: 1 in x)
```

Or create `DataFrame`, compare by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and test at least one `True` per rows by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
mask = pd.DataFrame(data['top-level'].tolist(), index=data.index).eq(1).any(axis=1)
```

EDIT:

```
print (data)
   top-level
0  [1,2,2,2]
1    [1,2,2]
2   [1,2, 3]
3    [4,5,6]

data = data['top-level'].apply(lambda x: any((number >= 1) and (number < 2) for number in x))
print (data)
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
Name: top-level, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to check if a value in x is between two values? 
Something like
`data['top-level'].apply(lambda x: 1 <= number < 2 for number in x)`

Comment: yes, but it always throws an error: `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`

Comment: Thank you, that is what I meant, the error disappeared.